# drupal 7, Как сделать фильтры как на данном сайте?

Tags: drupal, фильтры, views

На сайте есть фильры views.
При выборе марки всплывает дополнительное окно для выбора дальше.
[image: drupal7]

Вьюха настроена так фильтров.
[image: drupal7]

Есть таксономия, выглядит следующим образом.
Как сделать как на авто.ру? Чтобы при выборе левого фильтра в правый клались только под , относящиеся к нему?[image: drupal]

[image: drupal[![][4]]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvNal.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать hook_form_alter()
для формы фильтров, он будет вызываться каждый раз когда пользователь что то изменит в фильтрах.

И по своей логике вы сможете менять параметры в фыльтрах и убирать лишние или подгружать дополнительные